# How to change MongoDB local storage folder in Windows

Tags: mongodb, windows

When I installed Mongodb on windows, I created the data folder in `"C:\"` folder. However, I want to change it to folder `"C:\Mongo\data"`. I searched and tried this solution, but it didn't work as expected -

```
"C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.6\bin\mongod.exe" --dbpath c:\mongodb\data
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it does not work?"

Comment: After running the command, the folder `"C:\mongo"` still shows empty. I assumed the command didn't work

Comment: Did you try `--dbpath=c:\mongodb\data`?

Comment: It is working now. But whenever I restart the MongoDB, it is resetting the path. So I have to run the command again. Is there any way to do it permanently?

Comment: No, when you don't specify the folder then mongod takes the default path `\data\db`. But you could [install mongoDB as service](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongod.exe/) and use a [configuration file](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/).

Comment: If we install MongoDb as service file and then create a config file with dbpath as the `"C:\Mongo\data\db"`, the default path is as mentioned and not required to run the command later?

Comment: Don't get your point. Of course you should install the service with config file, i.e. `mongod.exe --config <...\mongod.cfg> --install` Then MongoDB will start automatically at boot time - that's the purpose of a service.

Comment: How to confirm if the command is working. A `.wt` file is getting updated in both the folders - `C:\Mongo\data\db` and `C:\Program Files\MongoDb\Server\4.4\bin\data`

Comment: Actually not possible. Did you start mongod.exe twice?

Comment: No. But whenever I am adding or deleting data in a db, both the folders are getting updated